# ReactJS | Pass Render Contents but ADD onClick

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to get some re-use out of my modals that I need to drop in various spots.  What I want to do is to separate the BUTTON that opens the modal from the modal itself.  This way, the button could be an icon button, a proper button or some other render-able thing.  I could be thinking about this wrong too.  I maybe, should pass the modal to the button?  Not sure, looking for advise.  I'm new to ReactJS, so don't assume I know a thing or two, I've made it through a few tutorials so far :D.

Here is a simple current implementation of the two components tied up together.  The problem child I think is the usage of the open State.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogActions,
  IconButton,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Edit } from "@mui/icons-material";
import FacilityForm from "./FacilityForm";

function EditFacilityModal(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (Facility) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      props.FacilitiesURL + "/" + String(Facility.ID),
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(Facility),
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) {
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        aria-label="expand row"
        size="small"
        onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}
      >
        <Edit />
      </IconButton>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Edit Facility</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please provide the following details to edit the existing facility
            in the system.
          </DialogContentText>
          <FacilityForm
            submitActions={handleSubmit}
            title="Edit Facility"
            details="Facility will be saved exactly as shown."
            Facility={props.Facility}
            FacilitiesURL={props.FacilitiesURL}
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditFacilityModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could outsource your Dialog into a seperate component which takes `open` and `handleClose` as props and other content as props i.e `dialogContentText` and `form` as a children prop

```js
function App(props) {
  const [openEditFacilityModal, setOpenEditFacilityModal] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpenEditFacilityModal(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenEditFacilityModal(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (Facility) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      props.FacilitiesURL + "/" + String(Facility.ID),
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(Facility),
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) {
    }
    setOpenEditFacilityModal(false);
  };

  return <div>
    <IconButton
      aria-label="expand row"
      size="small"
      onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}
    >
      <Edit />
    </IconButton>
    <EditFacilityModal open={openEditFacilityModal} handleClose={handleClose}>
      <FacilityForm
        submitActions={handleSubmit}
        title="Edit Facility"
        details="Facility will be saved exactly as shown."
        Facility={props.Facility}
        FacilitiesURL={props.FacilitiesURL}
      />
    </EditFacilityModal>
  </div>;
  
}


function EditFacilityModal({open, handleClose, dialogContentText, children}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Edit Facility</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
           {dialogContentText}
          </DialogContentText>
          {children}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditFacilityModal;
```

Comment: This is cool except of the leaking of the open/close state and handlers leaving the modal.  I was hoping to keep that all inside the modal.

Comment: This was closest to what I was looking for, be really great to solve the issue of component detail leakage into the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the button that handles the opening of the `modal` by handling the `open` state in a top level component.

Here's an example of your component that control the `open` state. This way you can outsource the `modal` component and use it anywhere with any button you want.

```
// MyComponent.jsx

import { Edit } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import EditFacilityModal from "./EditFacilityModal";

function MyComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton
        aria-label="expand row"
        size="small"
        onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}
      >
        <Edit />
      </IconButton>
      <EditFacilityModal
        open={open}
        handleClose={handleClose}
        Facility="Facility"
        FacilitiesURL="FacilitiesURL"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

```
// EditFacilityModal.jsx

import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@mui/material";
import FacilityForm from "./FacilityForm";

function EditFacilityModal(props) {
  const handleSubmit = async (Facility) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      props.FacilitiesURL + "/" + String(Facility.ID),
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(Facility),
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) {
    }
    props.handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={props.open} onClose={props.handleClose}>
      <DialogTitle>Edit Facility</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>
          Please provide the following details to edit the existing facility in
          the system.
        </DialogContentText>
        <FacilityForm
          submitActions={handleSubmit}
          title="Edit Facility"
          details="Facility will be saved exactly as shown."
          Facility={props.Facility}
          FacilitiesURL={props.FacilitiesURL}
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={props.handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default EditFacilityModal;
```

Comment: Cool except I end up with a full new component per button type.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I often use modals. A new component per button type sounds interesting.